# Why can't I sync my Unity project between 2 devices using Collaborate?

Tags: unity-game-engine, synchronization

I am new to Unity, and I am trying to sync 1 project between 2 devices (Windows / Mac) to make it more convenient.
I knew that most people use Github, but some say Collaboration can also work.

I started up a new project on the Windows PC and turned on Collab. I later went to my mac and opened up the remote project. However, my mac only showed a blank 3D scene. My Mac only synced the changes made from the Project Panel.

Is there something I have mistaken, and what should I do?

Thank you!

[Windows project(changes published)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjRCD.png)

[opening up Mac projected(blank scene)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSuqk.png)

[Chose the Windows platform on Mac(is that right?)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hof3L.png)

Comment: Can't help with Collab as I've never used it, but I encourage you to take another look at source control. Even if you're the only one working on a project on one computer it's still worthwhile because it gives you a history of what you've done and a safety net if you break something. It's pretty easy to break a Unity project in a way that may take a long time to repair where a restore from source control is quick and easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not in the correct scene on your mac

Open "Sample Scene", you currently have no saved scene open (hence it being called "Untitiled")

Comment: Thank you soooo much!!!!
I had been struggling with this for days!